# How to read a text file from X line in Java?

Tags: java, oop, file-management, randomaccessfile

How can I read a text file starting at X number line?
I can start reading the file and do nothing until X line is reached but I'm wondering if theres a better way to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to open a stream midway into a file.  Anything wrong with eating the first `X - 1` lines?

Answer (score 1):

In general you cannot do this unless you have a pre-built index of line lengths or line lengths in your file are known to be fixed. You can skip given number of *bytes* when reading random access file, but in order to skip given number of *lines* you should count the line-break symbols (like `\n`). The file system does not store the line break positions anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html). You can use it like the example below. But you need to know the position that you want to read. I am sure you can play with it a little bit and find how to use it.

```
private static byte[] readFromFile(String filePath, int position, int size) throws IOException {
    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "r");
    file.seek(position);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
    file.read(bytes);
    file.close();
    return bytes;
}
```

More info: 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/java_io_randomaccessfile.htm

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/randomaccessfile/java-randomaccessfile-example/